# Python Request Select() method - Selecting 'pre' Element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using Requests and BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage. Can't seem to get the select() method to work in order to grab the text seen in HTML below.

```
<head><style type="text/css"></style></head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
      "salePrice": 299.99
    }</pre>
  </body>
```

Tried the following with no luck, along with "#pre" and ".pre"

```
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
elems = page.select("pre")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

*Edit: I can't edit the HTML as its being scrapped from another's webpage

Comment: it works for me `page.select("pre")[0].text`

Comment: hmm says "list index out of range"

Comment: What's the output of `res.text` ?

Comment: Output of res.text is   '{\n  "salePrice": 299.99\n}'

Comment: There's your problem; `res.text` does not contain the `pre` tag.

Comment: Well, that certainly makes sense! haha - Any idea how to pull it properly then?

Comment: Can you post a full example rather than the current snippet that you have? That would certainly help in debugging.

Comment: if you put id="blah" and then.select("#blah")[0].text should work

Comment: Full HTML code is:
`<head><style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
  "salePrice": 299.99
}</pre></body>
<html hola_ext_inject="disabled"><head>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
  "salePrice": 299.99
}</pre>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: http://kochi-coders.com/2011/05/30/lets-scrape-the-page-using-python-beautifulsoup/ take a look at this easy tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link @FirebladeDan - unfortunately the example they use has a class attribute which makes it fairly easy to find. The HTML here is so sparse that im not sure what tag i need to select

Answer (score 0):

I am able to select the `pre` tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldoc = """<head><style type="text/css"></style></head> <body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{ "salePrice": 299.99 }</pre></body> <html hola_ext_inject="disabled"><head> <style type="text/css"></style></head> <body> <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{ "salePrice": 299.99 }</pre> </body> </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, 'html.parser')

print soup.select("pre")[0]
```

And what is printed:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{ "salePrice": 299.99 }</pre>
```